# Show Items to publish - in case of Linked component

Tags: dynamic-linking, linking

I have a component A which has component B linked through one of the  component link Field.
if i publish the component A , component B does not get published but if i publish component B , component A get published.
As per my knowledge, whenever i publish any component it publish all its dependent items such as multimedia components etc.

Why this odd behavior i am facing with linked component.

if my finding are correct, could somebody provide me the reason of this behavior with example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario of:

> A uses B

Publishing A does not cause B to be published.

Publishing B causes A to be published (A uses B, B is used by A).

It gets a bit more confusing once you add publishing status to the formula. Basically, it becomes `Republish all components that THIS item is used by`).

You can get a good feel for how it's all calculated by looking at the info in "Where Used". Items that show in the "Where Used" tab will be republished, items that show in the "Uses" tab will not be republished.

In other words, what you're experiencing is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Nuno. Now i have some a questions in my spined head - 
If only those items get published which are shown in the "Where Used" tab Why it is different with multimedia,if i publish a component A all multimedia components used in this component get published automatically?

Comment: Multimedia is published because your template publishes the binaries, not because of the relationships.

Comment: Since this question comes up fairly often, I [drew pictures](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/10/lets-play-what-published-that-aka-sdl.html) explaining what publishes what and how templates can publish binaries (and even extra component presentations).